# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar valores únicos a un arreglo?

Tags: c#, consola, array

Mi duda es la siguiente: 
Deseo ingresar n valores a un arreglo, estos valores son claves por lo tanto son unicas.

he logrado que me compare la clave actual con la anterior a la que ingreso actualmente pero no con todas las claves anteriores.

Estoy usando consola, C#.

Ayuda.

Comment: Hola Snacks, bienvenido a [es.so], para darte una solución a tu problema es necesario mostrar el fragmento de código, esto para darte una respuesta más puntual sin caer en especulación. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), si intentas cargar un duplicado te retorna `false`

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Add(1));
```

//true

```
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Add(2));
```

//true

```
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Add(1));
```

//false